# Ajuda em javascript e asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, razor

Em meu projeto tenho um campo que é o Status de determinada ocorrencia. Ou seja, se ela está pendente ou resolvida. Fiz uma função em javascript que , ao clicar o campo input que esta em modo readonly, muda o background. Digo, se a o valor de dentro do input for Resolvido, o input fica verde, e se o valor do input for Pendente fica vermelho.

O que acontece é que funciona direitinho, mas to tendo um problema: essa função só é feita na primeira ocorrência do input. Eu tenho uma index, e nela tem um foreach pra iterar sobre todos os dados do banco referente a ocorrencias, ou seja, tenho vários inputs sobre o status.

O que acontece é que a função só é executada na primeira ocorrência da lista, o restante não acontece nada.

Outra coisa é que, eu queria que ao salvar o ou editar a ocorrência, quando voltasse pra index pra mostrar, já se aplicasse a função, sem que o usuário precise clicar ou passar o mouse em cima. Fosse automático, digo, se o valor do input for Pendente, ficasse vermelho, se o valor for Resolvido ficasse verde.

Será que alguém pode me ajudar ?

## View(onde está todo o código)

```
@*@model IEnumerable<CEF01.Models.Ocorrencia>*@
    @model PagedList.IPagedList<CEF01.Models.Ocorrencia>
        @using PagedList.Mvc;
       <link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <style>
       #Status {
           text-align: center;
             }

        .resolvido {
    background-color: green;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    color: white;
           }

         .pendente {
    background-color: red;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    color: white;
        }
       </style>

        @{
          ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     }


       @Html.ActionLink("Criar uma nova ocorrência", "Adiciona", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
              @Html.ActionLink("Lista de Alunos", "Index", "Alunos", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

             <span class="pull-right">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Ocorrencias", FormMethod.Get))
            {
    <p>
        Busca Aluno: @Html.TextBox("busca")
        <input type="submit" value="Procurar" class="btn btn-info" />
    </p>
           }

           </span>

            <table class="table">
             <tr>
    <th>
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Aluno.Nome)*@
        Nome do Aluno
    </th>
    <th>
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Tipo)*@
        Tipo
    </th>
    <th>
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Causa)*@
        Causa
    </th>
    <th>
        @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)*@
        Descrição
    </th>
    <th>
        Status
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aluno.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tipo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Causa)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)*@
            <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly onmousemove="trocaCor()" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edita", new { id = item.Id }) |
            @* @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) | *@
            @Html.ActionLink("Remover", "Remove", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
        }

        </table>
          <br />
              Pagina @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) de @Model.PageCount
        @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagina => Url.Action("Index", new { pagina, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

       @section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    function trocaCor() {
        var troca = document.getElementById("Status");
        if (troca.value == "Pendente") {
            $("#Status").addClass("pendente");
        }
        if (troca.value == "Resolvido") {
            $("#Status").addClass("resolvido")
        }
    }
</script>
      }
```

Comment: Seria legal ter um título mais descritivo do problema real. E separar os parágrafos. Fica mais fácil das pessoas lerem, entenderem o que você quer e ajudarem.

Comment: Favor utilizar o http://www.jsfiddle.net para colocar seu código.

Comment: @bigown Melhorou ? O título é porque eu acho que assim fica melhor. Eu num sei um título que fiquei bem adequado com o problema, caso queira editar minha pergunta, pode ficar a vontade. Eu só queria uma ajuda pra poder resolver esse impasse. Penso que é uma coisa simples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se quiser que o javascript interaja com todos os objetos utilize classes. Pelo Id somente um será afetado.

Adicione a classe Status

```
<input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" class="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly onmousemove="trocaCor()" />
```

Script para carregar no index pra mostrar ja da cor correta:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Status').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "Pendente") {
            $(this).addClass("pendente");
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "Resolvido") {
            $(this).addClass("resolvido")
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Tem uma opção que não precisa nem de Javascript. Apenas com css e não precisa da classe tbm. Basta: http://jsfiddle.net/JH2tG/

```
<style>
    input[value=resolvido] { background-color: green }
    input[value=pendente] { background-color: red }
</style>
```

Comment: Poxa não funcionou dessa maneira. Ele nem trocou de cor.

Comment: Pressiona F12 no navegador e veja no console qual foi o erro de JS que te ajudo.

Comment: Ele até carrega o código, mas não aplica a função. Mas não da erro algum.

Comment: Voce pode fazer toda a chamada direto do JS também sem precisar chamar no input. Reparei que vc esta usando onmousemove pra chamar a função, tem outras formas melhores de fazer.

Comment: Pois é. Eu num quero que o usuário precise clicar ou mexer o mouse. Quero que ao carregar a página, de acordo com o valor do input já se aplique a função. E como que faria dessa forma ? Essa classe que você mencionou como que eu faria ela ? Pois coloquei aqui e não deu certo. Eu até tenho o estilo que quero na página, ta lá em cima !

Comment: Dessa forma você pode substituir o seu codigo pelo meu segundo exemplo de JS. Ao carregar a pagina (document.ready) ele varre todos os objetos (each) um por um com a classe Status verifica os valores e adiciona a classe.

Comment: Essa classe que ele adicionaria seria a que está no código javascript certo ?

Comment: A classe voce adiciona direto no input. <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" class="Status"... o jquery usa ela para achar o objeto. Voce estava anteriormente fazendo com o ID, porém ID o jquery subentende que é unico e so manipula o primeiro registro.

Comment: Recebi esse erro aqui com o seu código: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: trocaCor is not defined Ocorrencias:121
onclick'

Comment: Se der certo remova do input tambem esse onmousemove.

Comment: Se você quiser aplicar isso somente ao carregar a pagina vc tem que deixar somente esse segundo js q postei. Tem tambem que remover o onmousemove="trocaCor()"

Comment: Brother, funcionou certinho ! Dessa forma que você colocou !

Comment: Blz. Qualquer duvida so postar ai.

Comment: Tranquilo demais !

Answer (score 4):

Se você quer colorir o `input` conforme o status ao carregar a página, você pode fazer um seletor jquery para isto.
Em seu `input`, você está utilizando `id="Status"`, isto é inválido, não podemos ter vários elementos com o mesmo `id`, altere o `id="Status"` para `class="status"`, veja no exemplo:

HTML da view:

```
<input type="text" name="status" class="status" value="Pendente" readonly />
<input type="text" name="status" class="status" value="Resolvido" readonly />
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[value='Resolvido'].status").addClass('resolvido');
    $("input[value='Pendente'].status").addClass('pendente');
});
```

Exemplo: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zE9n8/)**

Comment: Muito top também sua solução cara ! Valeu demais !